# Update price automatically when quantity changed on product page Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I am looking to have the product price automatically updated based on the quantity the customer has chosen.

Currently when you choose a custom option in magento the price automatically updates but when choosing quantity this does not.

So the scenario would be the product price is £10. User enters 3 quantity and automatically on the product page it updates the price to £30 and so on.

Does anybody know of a simple way of updating this?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do this

```
$('#qty').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '' && isNumber($(this).val()) && $(this).val() > 0)
    {
       var price = $('#real_price').val() * 1;
       var qty = $(this).val() * 1;
       var total = price * qty;
       $('#price').html(total);
    }
    else
    {
       $('#price').html('500');    
    }
});

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hReB3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery::

HTML CODE::

```
<input type='number' id='quantity'/>
<span id='total_price'></span>
```

Jquery Code::

```
var price=100;
$("#quantity").on("change",function(){
    quantity=$(this).val();
    total_price=price*quantity;
    $("#total_price").html(total_price);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.2.4, the code file to edit is `js/varien/product.js`

In Magento 1.9.3 and above, the file to edit is `js/varien/product_options.js`

Add the following code:

```
var qty;
if($('qty').getValue().length == 0 || isNaN($('qty').getValue()) || $('qty').getValue() <= 0) { 
    qty = 1;
} else { 
    qty = $('qty').getValue();
    price *= qty;
}
```

right after

```
if (price < 0) price = 0;
```

and before

```
if (price > 0 || this.displayZeroPrice) { ...
```

And, at the end of the file add:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $('qty').observe('blur', function(e){
        optionsPrice.reload();
    });
});
```

*Source: https://magentojai.blogspot.com/2015/06/price-update-while-change-qty-in.html*

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script at the end in your `template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

```js
<script>
$('qty').observe('blur', function(e){
    $('qty').value = Math.max($F('qty').replace(/[^\d].*/, ''), 1);
    optionsPrice.productPrice = Math.max(optionsPrice.productOldPrice, $F('qty') * optionsPrice.productOldPrice);
    optionsPrice.reload();
});
</script>
```