# Dynamically/Automatically update price from qty on your magento product page

Tags: magento

Amend code to Dynamically update price from quantity on product page; works perfectly. Just add the identified code to public_html/js/varien/product.js

Copy and paste the first four lines of the code below into your product.js, before 'if (price > 0 || this.displayZeroPrice)', add the last five lines of code to the very end of the document; your done.  Save the file and watch your price update dynamically.

```
var qty;
if($('qty').getValue().length==0 || isNaN($('qty').getValue()) || $('qty').getValue() <= 0) qty = 1;
else qty = $('qty').getValue();
price*=qty; 
if (price > 0 || this.displayZeroPrice) {
formattedPrice = this.formatPrice(price);
} else {
formattedPrice = '';
}

if ($(pair.value).select('.price')[0]) {
$(pair.value).select('.price')[0].innerHTML = formattedPrice;
if ($(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix) && $(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).select('.price')[0]) {
$(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).select('.price')[0].innerHTML = formattedPrice;
}
} else {
$(pair.value).innerHTML = formattedPrice;
if ($(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix)) {
$(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).innerHTML = formattedPrice;
}
}
};
}.bind(this));
},
formatPrice: function(price) {
return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
}
}
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
if ($('qty')) $('qty') .observe('blur', function(e){
optionsPrice.reload();
});
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759664/update-price-automatically-when-quantity-changed-on-product-page-magento/61799914#61799914