# Jquery Grouped Products Pirce Total According to Quantity Magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento, product

I'm working on custom price total for grouped products using jquery. i want something like this. please check image and link for better understand

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqJ75.jpg

sample link : http://www.graduationsource.com/faculty/bachelors/cap-gown-tassel/adult-shiny-black-cap-gown-tassel.html

My Price Table

```
<?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered super-product-table1" id="super-product-table">
   <thead>

<tr>
<th valign="top" rowspan="3">Model Number</th>
<th valign="top" rowspan="3">Color</th>
<th valign="top" rowspan="3">Size</th>
<th valign="top" rowspan="3">Quantity per person</th>
<th valign="top" colspan="3">Price PER PERSON</th>
<th colspan="2">#OF CARTONS IN A CONTAINER LOAD</th>
<th colspan="2">CARTON PRICE PER CONTAINER LOAD</th>
<th rowspan="3">WEIGHT PER CARTON (IN LBS)</th>
<th rowspan="3">WANT IT FASTER<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="input3" /></th>
<th rowspan="3">DO YOU WANT A CONTAINER <input type="checkbox" id="hidecheckb"> </th>
<th colspan="3">ENTER QUANTITY (CARTONS OR CONTAINERS)</th>
</tr>


<tr>
<th valign="top" rowspan="2">1-2</th>
<th rowspan="2">3-5</th>
<th rowspan="2">6+</th>
<th rowspan="2">20 FOOT CONTAINER</th>
<th rowspan="2">40 FOOT CONTAINER</th>
<th rowspan="2">20 FOOT CONTAINER</th>
<th rowspan="2">40 FOOT CONTAINER</th>
<th rowspan="2">NUMBER OF CARTONS <br/></th>
<th valign="top" colspan="2">Number of containers<br/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>20 foot</th>
<th>40 foot</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>

    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): $i = $i+1; ?>
        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><?php echo $_item->getModel();  ?></td>
<td valign="top"><?php echo $_item->getcolour();  ?></td>
<td valign="top"><select><option value="">Select size</option><?php  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'select_size'); 
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option) {?>


    <option value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>"><?php echo $option['label']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>   </select>

</td>
<td valign="top"><?php echo $_item->getQuantityPerCarton();  ?> <input type="hidden" class="QuantityPerCarton" id="QuantityPerCarton<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getQuantityPerCarton();  ?>"></td>
<td valign="top"><?php echo $_item->getPricePerCorton();  ?><input type="hidden" class="PricePerCorton<?php echo $i; ?>" id="PricePerCorton<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getPricePerCorton();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getPricePerCortonSecond();  ?><input type="hidden" class="PricePerCortonSecond<?php echo $i; ?>" id="PricePerCortonSecond<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getPricePerCortonSecond();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getPricePerCortonThree();  ?><input type="hidden" class="PricePerCortonThree<?php echo $i; ?>" id="PricePerCortonThree<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getPricePerCortonThree();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getCartonsFortyContainerLoad();  ?><input type="hidden" class="CartonsFortyContainerLoad<?php echo $i; ?>" id="CartonsFortyContainerLoad<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getCartonsFortyContainerLoad();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getCartonsTwentyContainerLoad();  ?><input type="hidden" class="CartonsTwentyContainerLoad<?php echo $i; ?>" id="CartonsTwentyContainerLoad<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getCartonsTwentyContainerLoad();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getTwentyContainerLoadPrice();  ?><input type="hidden" class="TwentyContainerLoadPrice<?php echo $i; ?>" id="TwentyContainerLoadPrice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getTwentyContainerLoadPrice();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getFortyContainerLoadPrice();  ?><input type="hidden" class="FortyContainerLoadPrice<?php echo $i; ?>" id="FortyContainerLoadPrice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_item->getFortyContainerLoadPrice();  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $_item->getWeightPerCarton();  ?></td>
<td> $8</td>
<td><label></label></td>

<td> 
<div id="b" style="display:none"> <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
               <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" id="qty<?php echo $i; ?>"  value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?></div></td>

<td><div id="a" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="input"  class="input-text qty"></div></td>
<td><div id="a" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="input2"  class="input-text qty"></div></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
<td valign="top" colspan="10" rowspan="4">
 <div class="addorderinfbox">
   <div class="addordertxtarea">ADDITIONAL ORDER INSTRUCTIONS<br />
     <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="brandcuromdesign"><input type="submit" value="Brand IT" class="branditbtp">  <br/><input type="submit" value="Custom Colors" class="customitp">  <br/><input type="submit" value="Design It" class="designitp"></div>
 </div>
  </td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="select"> <option>Our Brand</option> </select></td>
<td colspan="5">$0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><select name="select2"> <option>No Custom Colors</option> </select></td>
<td colspan="5">$0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><select name="select3"> <option>No special design </option> </select></td>
<td colspan="5">$0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Total</td>
<td colspan="5"><p>$<span id="price">00</span></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" colspan="9">
<p>IF YOU CHOSE BRAND IT, CUSTOM COLORS OR DESIGN IT OPTIONS, PLEASE UPLOAD YOUR ARTWORK, LOGO OR COLOR SWATCHES BY CLICK THE “UPLOAD ARTWORK” BUTTON</p>
</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Upload ArtWork" class="uploadartworkpd"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="recaluculatebt" value="Recalculate cost"></td>
<td colspan="5"><button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button btn-cart validation-passed" type="button" rel="tooltip" data-original-title=""><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button></td>
</tr>
    <?php else: ?>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery working only for one quantity box

```
<script>


    jQuery('#qty2').keyup(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() != '' && isNumber(jQuery(this).val()) && jQuery(this).val() > 0)
    {
    var QuantityPerCarton =jQuery('#QuantityPerCarton').val() * 1;
    var qty = jQuery(this).val() * 1;

   if (qty <= 3) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCorton').val() * 1;
        }
        else if(3 <  qty && qty >= 5) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonSecond').val() * 1;
        }
        else if(5 <  $qty )  {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonThree').val() * 1;
        }

    var total = price * qty* QuantityPerCarton;
    jQuery('#price').html(total);
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery('#price').html('00');    
    }
});

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
</script>
```

please help !!!

Thanks in Advance

---

### Update

I have since managed to get it working after some changes but i need Grand total of all sub total of each Products and the loop is not working for 1 and 3 it is working for only 2 value of i

```
jQuery('.qty').keyup(function(){
    //get $i from the ID which we know to be 'qty[a number]'

     var values = jQuery(this).val();


    //we can then use that to get the appropriate fields
    if(values != '' && jQuery.isNumeric(values) && values > 0)
    {
   for (var i = 1, limit = 4; i <limit; i++) {


 var QuantityPerCarton =jQuery('#QuantityPerCarton'+i).val() * 1;

    //get the matching QuantityPerCarton value
    var qty = jQuery('#qty'+i).val() * 1;

   if (qty <= 3) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCorton'+i).val() * 1;
        }
        else if(3 <  qty && qty <= 5) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonSecond'+i).val() * 1;
        }
        else if(5 <  $qty )  {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonThree'+i).val() * 1;
        }

    var total = price * qty* QuantityPerCarton;
    jQuery('#price').html(total);
    }

    }
});
```

Comment: i have tried this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759664/update-price-automatically-when-quantity-changed-on-product-page-magento

but that is working me fine only for one quantity box

Comment: Okay. It sounds like you are getting close to a solution. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to narrow it down and include a [minimal example of the code you have so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If it's just a matter of making your script work for every quantity box I expect there will be several people proposing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are giving each of your quantity boxes a dynamic id

```
id="qty<?php echo $i; ?>" ...
```

... but your script is only looking for a keyup on one of them

```
jQuery('#qty2').keyup(function(){...
```

You need to update the script to listen for a keyup on ALL your quantity boxes. Seen as they share a common class of 'qty' we can use that:

```
jQuery('input.qty').keyup(function(){...
```

---

#### UPDATE

Further to your comments, you need some way to tie the quantity box to the associated hidden fields. Since you have appended $i to the id of these fields we can use that:

```
jQuery('input.qty').keyup(function(){
    //get $i from the ID which we know to be 'qty[a number]'
    var $i = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace('qty','');
    //we can then use that to get the appropriate fields
    if(jQuery(this).val() != '' && isNumber(jQuery(this).val()) && jQuery(this).val() > 0)
    {
    var QuantityPerCarton =jQuery('#QuantityPerCarton'+$i).val() * 1;//get the matching QuantityPerCarton value
    var qty = jQuery(this).val() * 1;

   if (qty <= 3) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCorton'+$i).val() * 1;
        }
        else if(3 <  qty && qty >= 5) 
        {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonSecond'+$i).val() * 1;
        }
        else if(5 <  $qty )  {
            price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonThree'+$i).val() * 1;
        }

    var total = price * qty* QuantityPerCarton;
    jQuery('#price').html(total);
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery('#price').html('00');    
    }
});
```

---

#### UPDATE 2

In your updated question you have a loop from 1 to 4. You can add the Grand Total price up as you go:

```
jQuery('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var values = jQuery(this).val();
    var grandTotal = 0;
    if(values != '' && jQuery.isNumeric(values) && values > 0){        
        for (i=1; <=4; i++) {
            var QuantityPerCarton =jQuery('#QuantityPerCarton'+i).val() * 1;
            //get the matching QuantityPerCarton value
            var qty = jQuery('#qty'+i).val() * 1;
            if (qty <= 3){
                price = jQuery('#PricePerCorton'+i).val() * 1;
            } else if(3 < qty && qty <= 5) {
                price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonSecond'+i).val() * 1;
            }
            else if(5 < $qty ) {
                price = jQuery('#PricePerCortonThree'+i).val() * 1;
            }                
            var subtotal = price * qty* QuantityPerCarton;
            grandTotal += subtotal;       
        }//end of loop
    jQuery('#price').html(grandTotal);    
    }
});
```

Comment: i have also passed dynamic id to price and QuantityPerCarton hidden input type. so how to call all those dynamically

Comment: You need some way to tie the quantity box to the associated hidden fields. See my update.

Comment: working after some changes but i need Grand total of all sub total of each Products.

Comment: I see you've posted your own answer too. You should really post this as a NEW question since your existing question has been answered.

Comment: sorry i can't ask more questions limit is over. please help me here :(