# Magento Custom Price Options

Tags: magento

Hi Newbie with Magento and hoping someone can assist. I need to change the frontend price of a product when two custom options dropdowns are selected with jquery/javacript. I have found some code in this question, but which file(s) do I put the code?
[code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759664/update-price-automatically-when-quantity-changed-on-product-page-magento)

Comment: Have you created any custom options for products in backend?

Comment: I've created the options on the backend without adding cost. The reason is that the cost needs to be multiplied by two options hence think I need to manually work out costing.